# Toggle show/hide optgroup children jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hide, toggle, show

I have a very long list of options, separated with optgroups. I'm trying to make each optgroup show/hide its children when clicked:

```
$("optgroup").toggle(function(){
    $(this).children().show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children().hide();
});
```

option list:

```
<form>
<select>
<optgroup label="a">
<option id="a1">a1</option>
<option id="a2">a2</option>
<option id="a3">a3</option>
<option id="a4">a4</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="b">
<option id="b1">b1</option>
<option id="b2">b2</option>
<option id="b3">b3</option>
<option id="b4">b4</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</form>
```

When I click on the optgroup, it doesn't toggle showing the children.

Comment: I don't think you can show/hide an optgroup tag. Instead I would look for a plugin replacement : http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: You can't select `<optgroup>`

Comment: thanks @jerome.s I'll use that

Answer (score 0):

Your toggle event is never executing because you cannot select an optgroup.

I would suggest using 2 select elements. Select the optgroup in the 1st and then update the second with the relevant options.

Comment: I think that wouldn't suit me, as it would be a bit time consuming for the user

Comment: Then I suggest using a select element with filtering so they can filter the select options at least.

Comment: @jerome.s above has recommended something which works perfectly - "chosen" is a stylesheet for laborious lists like mine which make use of the optgroups etc.